# Virtual box bridged ethernet having frequentdisconnections from with simulator

Tags: networking, virtualbox

i am running windows XP on my computer with oracle Virtual Box in it .

and i am running DEBIAN 6 as guest OS. and i bridged my adapter..

ip of XP is : 192.168.10.40
ip of debian (vbox) : 192.168.10.125

and  ping is too working

so when i run my linux application in debian 6 with switch simulator @ windows.i get frequently getting disconnected
am i missing some configurations or what

please help

Comment: Is your guest virtual machine bridged to a wireless adapter? If so, they have all sorts of problems in bridged mode.